# aligned equations with a case inside

Tags: equations

Please see the figure attached, I want to reproduce this set of equation, which code to use?

[image]

I tried this to have something similar but it doesnt work:

```
\begin{equation*}
\left\{ \,
\begin{multlined}
\phi_t + a \phi_x = 0.\\
\phi(x,0)=\phi_0(x)=\begin{cases}
\phi_L & \text{if } x<0,
\phi_R & \text{if } x>0,
\end{cases}
\end{multlined}
\right.
\end{equation*}
```

any simple ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `array` with `{cc}` column specifiers.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,papersize={10cm,4cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{cc}
\mbox{PDE:} & \phi_t + a \phi_x = 0.\\
\mbox{IC:} &\phi(x,0)=\phi_0(x)=
\begin{cases}
\phi_L & \text{if } x<0,\\
\phi_R & \text{if } x>0,
\end{cases}
\end{array}
\right \}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with stacks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\mycase}{%
\ensurestackMath{\tabularCenterstack{ll}{
u_L & \text{if } x<0,\\
u_R & \text{if } x>0,
}}}
\[\left.
\raisebox{6pt}{\tabularstackanchor[12pt]{cc}{PDE: & $u_t + au_x = 0$}
  {IC: & $u(x,0) = u_0(x) = \left\{\mycase\right.$}}
\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `gathered` and `alignat` environments, and the `empheq` package, with option `overload`:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}[right = \empheqrbrace]
& \begin{gathered}
\mathrm{PDE:}\\[\baselineskip]
\mathrm{IC:}
 \end{gathered}
 & \quad &
 \begin{gathered}
 \phi_t + a \phi_x = 0.\\[\baselineskip]
\phi(x,0)=\phi_0(x)=\smash{\begin{cases}
 \phi_L & \text{if } x<0,\\[1ex]
 \phi_R & \text{if } x>0.
 \end{cases}}
 \end{gathered}\\[-1ex]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]